# ng-show if ng-repeat returns no results

Tags: angularjs

I have a list generated by ng-repeat in angularjs.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="item.Show">
        <h4>Name: {{item.Name}}</h4>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-show="items.length == 0">
        <h4>No matching items</h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FGc3TTgQfWhx8OtXEQW1?s=0w82sTF5k9duukKJ
In this overly simplified example, I am showing a list generated from json objects based
on whether a boolean is set to true or false. How can I show a message in case no items oblige to this rule?
I only found answers related to text filtering so I hope this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a scope variable to check whether json has true items , Please check the below code.

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.Show" ng-show="hasResults" >
  <h4><p>Name: {{item.Name}}</p></h4>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item" ng-hide="hasResults">
  <h4>No matching items</h4>
</li>
```

and your controller function

```
function ItemController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.hasResults = false;

  $http.get('items.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      if (item.Show && !$scope.hasResults) {
        $scope.hasResults = true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="Object.keys(items).length > 0">
        <h4>Name: {{item.Name}}</h4>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-if="Object.keys(items).length <= 0">
        <h4>No matching items</h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```